# Program no longer able to read or write to files after it's segment being exported into a dll

Tags: c++, dll

I turned my c++ application project into a dll project and moved the main method into a new, separate application project (within the same solution).

However, any parts of the code which were writing to files or reading from them prior to this change are now failing. No errors are thrown, but anything that is supposed to be written isn't, and anything that is supposed to be read results with an empty string (`""`).

I tried running this bit of code from the dll:

```
std::ofstream outfile("test.txt");
outfile << "my text here!" << std::endl;
outfile.close();
```

I could not find "test.txt" anywhere within my solution.

Why is dll code acting this way?

**EDIT:**

Note that I ran the same code prior to the change into the dll and the code ran fine, reading and writing everything it should have. I then did this and it broke. I made no other changes other than that. All the files are still in the same place.

Comment: Check the state of the stream. You may be trying to read/write files in a directory where you don't have permission. Another thing to note is that these paths will be relative to your current working directory, which is usually the same as your executable. Look around there to make sure the files aren't present.

Comment: Note that I ran the same code 10min ago when the code was still an .exe. It woked fine then. It doesn't now. Nothing has changed.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions

Comment: Unable to read memory. Number associated with error was -858993460.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project and then accessed the dll from it. That means that my working directory was the new .exe project, not the old .exe project (now the dll).

Hence, I had to copy all the resources to the new project and it all worked from there.

As it goes for not writing to disk, I'm experiencing some kind of explorer lag where folders don't refresh automatically when files are added - all the created files were there, I just wasn't seeing them, (but git did - thank you git).